# Does Forza Motorsport 5 have a Co-op Mode?

Tags: forza-motorsport-5

I am considering buying Forza Motorsport 5, but I prefer co-op games.

Does Forza Motorsport 5 have a co-op mode?  If so, what does it entail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It doesn't have a "co-op mode", in that the career progression is single player. This is the mode in which you unlock experience and earn credits.

There is split screen racing, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  It does have an online multiplayer mode though, right?

Comment: Yes, but again it's just racing. You're competing, not cooperating. :) it is a great game though, def. recommend it if you have an xbox one. And you could pass the pa between career races if you like.

Comment: Pad, sorry. Typing on my phone is hit and miss. :)